# how can i correct this double keyword decipher?

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub decrytpion()
    Dim plain As String
    Dim keyword As String
    Dim keyword2 As String
    Dim encoded_message() As Integer

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red

    Console.Write("Enter your plaintext: ")
    plain = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    Console.Write("Enter your keyword: ")
    keyword = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    Console.Write("Enter your second keyword: ")
    keyword2 = Console.ReadLine.ToUpper()

    While plain.Length > keyword.Length
        keyword = keyword + keyword
    End While

    While plain.Length > keyword2.Length
        keyword2 = keyword2 + keyword2
    End While

    keyword = Asc(keyword)        'finds out ascii value of keyword

    keyword2 = Asc(keyword2)    'finds out ascii value of keyword2

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta

    Console.WriteLine("here is your decrypted message")

    ReDim Preserve encoded_message(0 To plain.Length - 1)
    For stepper As Integer = 0 To plain.Length - 1
        encoded_message(stepper) = Asc(plain(stepper)) - keyword - keyword2 + 96
        Console.Write(Chr(encoded_message(stepper)))

    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

it is meant to decipher a word put in by shifting each letter down alphabet a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

> plain = Console.ReadLine<s>.ToUpper()</s>

Don't convert the case of the input text.

> keyword = Asc(keyword)        'finds out ascii value of keyword
>
> keyword2 = Asc(keyword2)    'finds out ascii value of keyword2

Delete/comment out these two lines.

> encoded_message(stepper) = Asc(plain(stepper)) - keyword - keyword2 + 96

Change this to:

```
encoded_message(stepper) = Asc(plain(stepper)) - Asc(keyword(stepper)) - Asc(keyword2(stepper)) + 128
```

This will correct 4 problems:

1. You were converting the keywords to ASCII outside of your `stepper` loop, giving you one constant value for each rather than a different letter for each value of the keyword.
2. You were converting input strings to uppercase ("A" = 65) but using the ASCII value for lowercase ("a" = 97) in decryption.
3. When building the `encoded_message` array, you only added back the ASCII/integer difference once. Since you subtracted two characters, you need to add it back twice.
4. You converted the case of the input text, but the nature of the encoding used means this will change the result in some cases. My revised code still assumes the *original* message was converted to uppercase before encoding, but the *encrypted* message **might very well contain lowercase letters**, as lowercase letters have higher values than lowercase ones and the message is encrypted by adding values. (Example: message "J" with keywords "Q" and "X" encrypts as "s".) **If this is not the behavior you intended** (i.e. if encryption is supposed to "loop" around the alphabet so that message "J" with keywords "Q" and "X" encrypts as "Y") then the code will need to be edited further to **use the Mod operator to find correct values.**